# Unit determinant for relevant symmetry groups in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, group-theory, s-matrix-theory, unitarity

When treating QFT we want our theory to be invariant under different symmetry groups, for example, the Standard Model is a non-abelian gauge theory with the symmetry group $U(1)×SU(2)×SU(3)$. Moreover, it is invariant under Lorentz transformations which form the Lorentz group $O(1,3)$ with the proper transformations subgroup $SO(1,3)$ In this example $S$ stands for Special, meaning that these transformations are represented by matrices with determinant $1$.

My questions are:

1. why is this requirement so important?
2. In particular, what would happen if we allow the determinant to be any real (or complex) number?

Comment: The determinant of an orthogonal matrix is already restricted to being either 1 or -1, so it couldn't be just any number!

Comment: ok, but why not -1 then?

Answer (score 4):

To preserve the [notion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_%28physics%29) of probabilities in QFT, symmetries must be implemented as unitary or antiunitary operations. See also [Wigner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem)'s [theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wigner+theorem). For finite-dimensional representations, the determinant of such operations must be just a phase factor.

*Example:* $U(1)$ symmetry.